# Laravel 5.4 - Socialite Providers multiple configurations with Twitter

Tags: twitter, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

I have two services to connect with Socialite Provider:

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use \SocialiteProviders\Manager\Config;

public function connect_1() {
    $config1 = new Config(
        env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_1'),
        env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_1'),
        env('TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI_1'),
        [
            //
        ]
    );

    return Socialite::with('twitter')->setConfig($config1)->redirect();
}

public function connect_2() {
    $config2 = new Config(
        env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_2'),
        env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_2'),
        env('TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI_2'),
        [
            //
        ]
    );

    return Socialite::with('twitter')->setConfig($config2)->redirect();
}
```

But, I have this error when I try this code:

> Configuration for TWITTER_KEY is missing. There is no services entry
>   for twitter

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: No, sorry I didn't solve it...

Comment: Why isn't there any solution, not even on stackoverflow :(

Comment: It's very hard to find the solution :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this  will work after 
https://packagist.org/packages/socialiteproviders/manager

```
$clientId = "secret";
$clientSecret = "secret";
$redirectUrl = "yourdomain.com/api/redirect";
$additionalProviderConfig = ['site' => 'meta.stackoverflow.com'];
$config = new \SocialiteProviders\Manager\Config($clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUrl, $additionalProviderConfig);
return Socialite::with('provider-name')->setConfig($config)->redirect();
```